# How to include new component in axios response

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I have an component with text input. After fill input and submit form i sand axios query and after response i need stay on the same page with error popup or include new component with response data.

my component

```
<template>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-container">
        <form v-on:submit="prepareCollage()" class="main-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">
                <input placeholder="your text" v-model="text" name="query" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button class="go btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            text : '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        prepareCollage(){
            event.preventDefault();
            axios.get('/api/prepare?query='+encodeURIComponent(this.text))
                .then(function(result){

                    const result_data = result.data;

                    // if controller gave an error
                    if(result_data.error === true){

                        let error_text = result_data.error_text;
                        if(typeof(result_data.with_link) != 'undefined' && result_data.with_link.length > 0){
                            error_text += "<a href='"+result_data.with_link+"'>"+result_data.link_text+"</a>";
                        }

                        Vue.swal({
                           title: 'Error!',
                           html: error_text,
                           type: 'error',
                        })

                    }else{

                       // here i need include new component
                    }

            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

in "else" block i have to include new vue component with data from this component. I have never used vuejs and have difficulty with understand this.

Comment: Just use a [v-if](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) and have the dynamic component already declared on the page.

Comment: ok, i added <template v-if="mainPage === true"> </template> <template v-else> </template> and in my data() function setup mainPage: true. But always include "v-else" template

Comment: If you have another component, you can import it and then just use it's name.  Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/r0qwnzwz3q) example.  Open the components folder and look at the Hello and Test components.